# How to combine many COUNTs into one big query in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I am using SQLite and performing many COUNT queries using a loop like so...

```
foreach (var eventId in eventIds)
{
    Database.Query("SELECT COUNT(RowId) FROM Images WHERE EventId = " + eventId);
}
```

...each of these queries only takes something like 12ms but this adds up and can lead to 10 seconds of waiting. Is it possible to combine this into one query and an array of event ids?

Like...

```
SELECT COUNT(RowId) FROM Images WHERE EventId IN (10329, 10312, 10328, etc...)
```

... but obviously with individual COUNT's coming back?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to get the count relative to an event.

```
SELECT eventid,
       count(*)
       FROM images
       WHERE eventid IN (4711,
                         747,
                         ...)
       GROUP BY eventid;
```

This will return something like:

```
eventid | count
========+======
   4711 |    31
    747 |    99
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks, you were just one minute slower than the first guy.

Comment: @AzzyDude: Actually I was one minute faster (earlier). ;) You're reading the numbers wrong. But never mind. ;)

Comment: Today is not my day!!

Answer (score 3):

try this: this will give you count per event

```
SELECT EventId ,COUNT(RowId) FROM Images WHERE EventId IN (10329, 10312, 10328, etc...)
group by EventId
```

Comment: Oh it's that easy? I'm dumb.